# Why do I get a Wrong signature with HeapTrc?

Tags: lazarus

I simplified the following code at the maximum to only show my problem.
When the destructor TClass3.Destroy is done, the action FreeAndNil(FClass3) causes a problem and the program stops. If have a look in the Heap.trc file I can read

Marked memory at $0000000001528FD0 invalid
Wrong signature $2951FD2D instead of 5C063D8B

```
program Project_testFree;
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  sysutils;

type
  TClass1 = class
  private
  protected
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

  TClass2 = class(TClass1)
  private
  protected
    FTClass2   : cardinal;
  public
  end;

  TClass3 = class
  private
  protected
    FClass3       : TClass1;
  public
    constructor Create;virtual;
    destructor Destroy;override;
  end;

  TClass4 = class(TClass3)
  private
    function GetLocalClass2: TClass2;
  protected
  public
    constructor Create;override;
    destructor destroy;override;
    property pClass2:TClass2 read GetLocalClass2;
  end;

constructor TClass1.Create;
begin
  inherited;
end;

constructor TClass3.Create;
begin
  FClass3               := TClass1.create;
end;

destructor TClass3.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FClass3);
  writeln('Destroy');
  inherited Destroy;
end;

constructor TClass4.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  pClass2.FTClass2 := 1;
end;

destructor TClass4.destroy;
begin
  inherited destroy;
end;

function TClass4.GetLocalClass2: TClass2;
begin
  result := TClass2(FClass3);
end;

var
  c:TClass4;
begin
  if FileExists('heap.trc') then
   DeleteFile('heap.trc');
  SetHeapTraceOutput('heap.trc');

  c:=TClass4.Create;
  c.free;
end.
```

I use Lazarus 1.6.2.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Heap corruption by your code?  Anyway, this is probably not related to your problem, but you should always include an explicit, absolute path in your file names.

Comment: I think this is not related to my problem, and I didn't think the absolute path is necessary if I want to get the file in the same directory of my application

Comment: Are you assuming you have write access to your app's directory?

Comment: Yes my app's directory is write access. @David pointed me my error.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cast `FClass3` to be `TClass2`. But you instantiated `TClass1`. The cast is therefore incorrect which would explain the error. Essentially, you lied to the compiler and it exacted its revenge.

Had you used a checked cast, using `as`, then a runtime error would have been raised.

Comment: You are right David, I didn't see it. I will remenber one important thing which is to not cast without be sure. As you wrote using 'as' raise an error. I will re-arrange my code like **constructor TClass4.Create; begin inherited Create; FLocalClass2:=TClass2.Create; FLOcalClass2.FTClass2:=1; end; destructor TClass4.destroy; begin FreeAndNil(FLocalClass2); inherited destroy; end;**

Comment: You need to sort out the naming of your classes. You also should not name instances classes.